# Accessing raw OpenFDA data for visualizations

Tags: openfda

Is there a way to connect a Tableau [Web Data Connector](https://community.tableau.com/community/developers/web-data-connectors) to the data on the [OpenFDA API](https://open.fda.gov/api/)?

Comment: tableau doesn't use open data.

Comment: tableau can use open data via [web data connectors](https://community.tableau.com/community/developers/web-data-connectors), which are maintained by the community. I'll re-write the question to be more clear.

Comment: Voted to reopen. This question in its current form would *not* be accepted on [SO].

Comment: i don't see how the reworded question fits here. community maintenance does not mean the format is open, reusable, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can write a custom web data connector that Tableau then uses to "scrape" any webpage or webservice (API)

> With the Web Data Connector SDK, you can unlock a world of data that's available over the web. In addition to using the dozens of data connectors that are already available in Tableau, you can now create your own web data connector (WDC) that reads data from virtually any site that publishes data in JSON, XML, or HTML.

There are some official connectors, and the community maintains unofficial ones.

So far there is no public OpenFDA connector, but you can write your own.

- [Documentation](https://community.tableau.com/community/developers/web-data-connectors)
- [Official Connectors](https://github.com/tableau/webdataconnector)
- [Community Connectors](http://tableau.github.io/webdataconnector/community/)
- [Example Dashboard](http://public.tableau.com/views/openFDAAdverseEvents/openFDA) using non-public connector (I presume)